# Why custom DialogPreference doesnt trigger on onSharedPreferenceChanged listener?

Tags: android, listener, sharedpreferences, dialog-preference

I am trying to make dialog preference in preferences, where user just click positive button to trigger some action. (Clear database? No | Yes)

```
public class MyDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public MyDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "# onDialogClosed: " + positiveResult);
    }

}
```

I dont actually want to persist anything, just trigger  onSharedPreferenceChanged listener, so I can handle it in the activity. But I cant figure out how to trigger it

//SOLUTION

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
    if(positiveResult) {
        persistBoolean(!getPersistedBoolean(true));
    }
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "# onDialogClosed: " + positiveResult);
}
```

Comment: Maybe call `notifyChanged()` or `callChangeListener()`in your `onDialogClosed()`? I think callChangeListener is what you need.

Comment: I tried that as first, It doesnt work -.-

Comment: May I know why must use persistBoolean? Can we use other like persistLong...

Comment: @CheokYanCheng its doesnt matter, you can use long, boolean is just "handy" because you can "toggle" true false with ! operator to always trigger the listener and dont worry about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onSharedPreferenceChanged` is called because of the inbuilt callback registered on the `sharedpreference`, so unless you change the key associated with dialogPreference you are not going to get the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` callback.

So what you could do is everytime dialog is closed, you could change the value in key. Something like below

```
text = getPersistedString("1")
if(text.length() > 10)
   text = "1";
persistString(text+"1");
```

Make sure your dialogPreference has a key and android:persistent as true in xml