# onCreateDialogView and onDialogClosed are not found in v7 support DialogPreference

Tags: android

Previously, I'm using `PreferenceFragment`. Hence, to invoke a custom dialog from `PreferenceFragment`, I will use `DialogPreference` as following.

### ScanSpeedDialogPreference.java

```
import android.preference.DialogPreference;

public class ScanSpeedDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public ScanSpeedDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.scan_speed_dialog_preference);
    }

    public ScanSpeedDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.scan_speed_dialog_preference);
    }   

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        View view = super.onCreateDialogView();

        // Perform all UI fine tuning and event handler installation...

        return view;
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851554/why-custom-dialogpreference-doesnt-trigger-on-onsharedpreferencechanged-listener
    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        if (positiveResult) {
            persistBoolean(!getPersistedBoolean(true));
        }
    } 
}
```

Recently, I'm under migration code from `PreferenceFragment` to `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

Hence, I can no longer use `DialogPreference`.

I need a class, which is subsclass from `android.support.v7.preference.Preference`

I try to change my `DialogPreference`, to the following

### ScanSpeedDialogPreference.java

```
import android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference;

public class ScanSpeedDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public ScanSpeedDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.scan_speed_dialog_preference);
    }

    public ScanSpeedDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.scan_speed_dialog_preference);
    }   

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        View view = super.onCreateDialogView();

        // Perform all UI fine tuning and event handler installation...

        return view;
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851554/why-custom-dialogpreference-doesnt-trigger-on-onsharedpreferencechanged-listener
    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        if (positiveResult) {
            persistBoolean(!getPersistedBoolean(true));
        }
    } 
}
```

However, 2 problems arise.

1. v7 `DialogPreference` doesn't have `onCreateDialogView`.
2. v7 `DialogPreference` doesn't have `onDialogClosed`.

I was wondering, what is the proper way, to achieve similar functionality of `onCreateDialogView` and `onDialogClosed` in v7 `DialogPreference`?

Comment: https://medium.com/@boramaapps/dialog-inside-android-preferences-1c50f93d2e8c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using support library, please do not use `DialogPreference`. Instead, we should use `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`.

For detailed information, please refer to [Adding toolbar to PreferenceActivity via AppCompatPreferenceActivity causes overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953166/adding-toolbar-to-preferenceactivity-via-appcompatpreferenceactivity-causes-over)